# asp.net mvc3 disable masterpage for view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I disable the usual _Layout.cshtml for one view.

I try to use the content of the view aboutuser.cshtml to populate a div using ajax. Do you think this is a correct approch?

```
 $('#SelectUser').click(function () {

            $('#userPlace').html('<strong>Loading...</strong>');
            $.post('InfoFor?userSelect=' + ($('#usersoption:selected').val()), function (data) {
                $('#userPlace').html(data);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside this view/partial:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

or from the controller action serving it return a `PartialView` instead of a `View`:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```